# Non-static inner classes like this can only by instantiated using default, no-argument constructor error when deserialize

Tags: java, deserialization

I am trying to serialize and deserialize my object but I got an error during deserialization:

```
Cannot construct an instance of 'MyObject' (although at least one Creator exists): 
non-static inner classes like this can only be instantiated using a default, no-argument constructor.
```

I had constructor for class MyObject with 2 parameters but I changed it to default constructor, but it still throw the same error.

This is my code:

```
@Test
public void serializeAndDeserializeTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
    var list = new MyObject[2];
    var t1 = new MyObject();
    t1.value1 = TestEnum.VALUE5.numVal;
    t1.value2 = "A";
    var t2 = new MyObject();
    t2.value1 = TestEnum.VALUE1.numVal;
    t2.value2 = "B";
    list[0] = t1;
    list[1] = t2;
    var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    var json = mapper.writeValueAsString(list);
    MyObject[] output = mapper.readValue(json, MyObject[].class);
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int value1;
    public String value2;
}

public enum TestEnum
{
    VALUE1(1),
    VALUE3(3),
    VALUE5(5);

    public int numVal;

    TestEnum(int numVal) {
        this.numVal = numVal;
    }
}
```

I also tried to create a private default constructor but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to fix this, make the `MyObject` inner class static:

```
public static class MyObject {
    public int value1;
    public String value2;
}
```

Without the static keyword, the inner class needs an instance of the encompassing outer class in order to exist. This is what causes the exception.

For the `enum` that is not the case because inner enums are implicitly static, see the [Java Language Specification, chapter 8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)